# Xcode - Add Custom Documentation for Swift Closure

Tags: swift, xcode, documentation, apple-documentation

## Question:

- What is the correct **format** to add documentation (using built in functionality not 3rd party) to a custom `Swift` closure in `Xcode 8` ?
- Could you provide the **Apple documentation link** to refer ?
- How to specify the `closure` `parameters` ?
- How to specify the `closure` `return type` ?

Example:

```
struct S1 {

    /// This block is executed after completion
    var completion : (String, Int) -> (Bool)
}
```

## Note:

`Xcode 8` has built in functionality to add documentation to custom code.

This can be done, by doing one of the following:

- `Command` + `Option` + `Click` on code
- Keep cursor on code and `Editor` > `Structure` > `Add documentation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Reference:

- For reference see [Markup Formatting Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/SymbolDocumentation.html) namely the section "Formatting Quick Help"

## Workaround:

If those tags are not supported for the given location the only possible workaround seems to be right now:

```
struct S1 {
    
    /// description
    ///
    /// __returns__
    /// blah blah
    ///
    /// __parameters__
    /// blah blah
    var completion : (String, Int) -> (Bool)
}
```

Comment: The parameter and return type are not showing up. Only the description shows up for Swift Code.

Comment: ahh ok, now I understand the question! Added a paragraph to my answer. Sadly thats not going to change with Xcode9.